# Python variables being returned as blank after using .get()

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

For the rest of my program, .get() has worked, however, when I have tried creating a new class and set of attributes for the class, the .get() method doesn't work, only working on variables inherited from my previous class. I am trying to use .get() to take the variable from an entry in one screen and use in a function in the same class.

```
class Main:

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self._frame = None
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.var_FName = StringVar()
        self.var_SName = StringVar()
        self.var_password1 = StringVar()
        self.var_usertype = StringVar()
        self.UserID = StringVar()
        self.StudName = StringVar()
        self.var_classname = StringVar()
        self.var_classnamedel = StringVar()
        self.var_studname = StringVar()
        self.var_studname_remadd = StringVar()
        self.studnameedit = StringVar()
        self.editclassname = StringVar()
        self.studname_editor = StringVar()

class Teacher (Main):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self._frame = None
        self.StudName = StringVar()
        self.var_classname = StringVar()
        self.var_classnamedel = StringVar()
        self.var_studname = StringVar()
        self.var_studname_remadd = StringVar()
        self.studnameedit = StringVar()
        self.editclassname = StringVar()
        self.studname_editor = StringVar()

    def classchanges(self, editclass1st, teachmain):
        editclass1st.destroy()

        advchanges = Toplevel(teachmain)
        advchanges.geometry("896x693+549+165")
        advchanges.title("Edit Classes")

        Label(advchanges, text = "Enter name of class to edit:", font = ("Calibri", 14)).place(relx=0.056, rely=0.173, height=31, width=271)
        Entry(advchanges, textvariable = self.editclassname).place(relx=0.078, rely=0.231,height=20, relwidth=0.283)


    def displayclassedit(self, advchanges, user_searchresult):
        user_searchresult.delete(0, 'end')
        print (self.editclassname.get())
```

I have added the parts of the concerning the variable and its use. I simply get a blank return and not sure why

Comment: `teacher.__init__` needs to call `super().__init__()`.

Comment: create minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see problem.